# Solve the equation: $\lfloor a/2\rfloor+\lfloor a/3\rfloor+\lfloor a/5\rfloor=a$, where $a> 0$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $a$ we can write it as $a = 30k + i$, where $i\in\{0,1,2,\ldots, 29\}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_0^+$. Thus substituting we have:
\begin{align*}
     \lfloor(30k + i)/2\rfloor + \lfloor(30k + i)/3\rfloor + \lfloor(30k + i)/5\rfloor &= 30k + i\\
     \lfloor 15k + (i/2)\rfloor + \lfloor 10k + (i/3)\rfloor + \lfloor 6k + (i/5)\rfloor &= 30k + i\\
     15k + \lfloor i/2\rfloor + 10k + \lfloor i/3\rfloor + 6k + \lfloor i/5\rfloor &= 30k + i\\
     31k + \lfloor i / 2 \rfloor + \lfloor i / 3 \rfloor + \lfloor i / 5 \rfloor & = 30k + i \\
     k &= i - (\lfloor i/2\rfloor + \lfloor i/3\rfloor + \lfloor i/5\rfloor)
\end{align*}
Thus we have for each $i$ we will have a value of $k$. Also note that if $i=0$,
\begin{align*}
     k &= 0 -(\lfloor 0/2\rfloor + \lfloor 0/3\rfloor + \lfloor 0/5 \rfloor) \Rightarrow k=0.
\end{align*}
So $a=0$, but $a>0$. So $i=0$ is not taken, for all others we have a solution.

I think this is the correct solution, I await your comments. If anyone has a different solution or correction of my work I will be grateful.

Comment: +1, not merely for showing your work but (in a moment of weakness) I am (also) responding in a positive manner to your **outstanding** approach of $a = 30k + i.$  I actually didn't even have to read the rest of your work.  Once I saw that, I knew how I was going to react to your query, which I regard as a breath of fresh air, compared to the usual queries posted on mathSE.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Your words have made my day.

Comment: Well done, indeed. Because you are so close to a full description of the alternatives I would consider including the list: $k=1$ if 
$$i\in\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 23, 29\}$$ and $k=0$ otherwise. Admittedly this cannot be written in a more elegant form. At least not easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an excellent solution.

It would perhaps be a good idea, after obtaining
\begin{align*}
     k &= i -(\lfloor i/2\rfloor + \lfloor i/3\rfloor + \lfloor i/5 \rfloor) 
\end{align*}
to show that $k$ is non-negative. This is not totally trivial and, since$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}>1,$$ it is only just true.